# Using Scrollorama with Cycle Plugin and jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I incorporate the Scrollorama plugin into my webpage, the Cycle plugin stops functioning. I tried incorporating jQuery.noConflict but it still doesn't work. Am I implementing the jQuery.noConflict() wrong or is it something else?:

Links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.scrollorama.js"></script>
```

Scrollorama Plugin:

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
var scrollorama = $j.scrollorama({
    blocks:'.scrollblock'
});
});
</script>
```

Cycle Plugin:

```
<script>

$(function(){

$('#play').click(function(){ $('#slider').cycle('resume'); return false;}); 

$('#pause').click(function(){ $('#slider').cycle('pause'); return false;});

$('#slider').cycle({
  fx:       'scrollHorz',
  next:     '#next',
  prev:     '#previous',
  pager:    '#pager',
  timeout:  5000,
  speed:    500
});
});
</script>
```

I've tried doing different options from different questions in the past but none of them work. Could this be an issue with the plugins and not how I implement them into my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) and for weeks I could not crack it, until I discovered console. Console allowed me to track all the JS errors.

If you embed the files in this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.scrollorama.js"></script>
```

Then put all your code in:

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

Example:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollorama = $j.scrollorama({
      blocks:'.scrollblock'
    });
  });

  $('#play').click(function(){ $('#slider').cycle('resume'); return false;}); 

  $('#pause').click(function(){ $('#slider').cycle('pause'); return false;});

  $('#slider').cycle({
    fx:       'scrollHorz',
    next:     '#next',
    prev:     '#previous',
    pager:    '#pager',
    timeout:  5000,
    speed:    500
  });
})(jQuery);
```

It should work fine.

For [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/), the example has the jQuery is embedded in the body. For extra jQuery plugins on the page, TweenMax and jquery.min need to be moved into the head in the following sequence:

```
<head>
  ... Your Meta, CSS files, ...
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  ... Your other jQuery files, mootools, ...
</head>
```

Your CSS files may appear above or below the `jQuery.noConflict();` but all your jQuery MUST appear after TweenMax.

`jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js` and `jquery.superscrollorama.js` may remain in the body. Just remember to add `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);` around all your code:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // set rotation of flash
        TweenMax.set("#newversion", {rotation: 15});
    ... and so on ...
})(jQuery);
```